# Linetype in ggplot stat_ecdf not visible for large datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using GGPlot2 to plot an empirical distribution function for a large dataset (170k rows). Unfortunately, the linetype is not clearly visible (due to overplotting?).

Any thoughts?

```
test = data.frame(
  a = c(rnorm(75000)*100,rnorm(75000)*100+50),
  b = c(rep('a', 75000),rep('b', 75000))
)

ggplot(test, aes(a, linetype = factor(b))) + 
  stat_ecdf()
```

Comment: From your question and plot, it's not entirely sure what the problem is. Could you clarify exactly what the problem is and how you've tried to solve it? Also, your code is not reproducible.

Comment: ... and why not use color to help make it clear?

Comment: I have updated the post, hope this helps. Using color works fine indeed, I want to use linetype for noncolor printing.

Comment: It's because the number of "steps" far outweighs the gaps in the the linetype. Try `+ stat_ecdf(n = 500)` to see.

Comment: Thanks, I'm embarrassed by how simple the solution was!

Comment: Go ahead and write up an official answer yourself if you like. Then you can accept it as well (after a short waiting period).

Comment: @joran, why wouldn't you write the answer yourself?

Comment: @DavidArenburg <shrug> Because I don't care that much. If no one has written an answer in a few hours, I'll probably write one just to clean up the question.

Comment: @joran, Then we will wait :)

Comment: @joran credit to whom credit is due! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the number of "steps" far outweighs the gaps in the the linetype.

You can try turning on interpolation using `+ stat_ecdf(n = 500)` to see the difference. When you don't set the `n` argument, it uses all the data, and in your specific case there are simply so many "step" points that there aren't enough pixels to show the linetype.